# how to create child nodes with php xpath query

Tags: php, xpath

Code is something like this:

```
$b = $xpath->query('//td[@class="abc"]');
foreach ($b as $b2) { /*contents*/ }
```

Inside td, this contents will be there:

```
<h2><a href="http://www.example.com/" title="this is link">Link Title</a>
    <span class="spanclass">Spinning</span></h3>
<div class="xyz">ABC XYZ abc xyz</div>
<span class="phr">Style</span>red
```

if i print/echo, "print_r ($b2->nodeValue);", content will be like this:

```
Link Title
  Spinning
 ABC XYZ abc xyz
 Style red
```

Now tried, this code inside each $b2:

```
foreach ($xpath->query('.//a[@href]', $b2) as $child) {
   print_r($child->nodeValue);
}
```

Answer is coming:

```
Link Title
```

I need this information from there:

```
$title = 'Link Title';
$titlelink = 'http://www.example.com';
$spanclassinfo = 'Spinning';
$stylerandom = 'red';
```

Any help?
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

You should check if it has attributes with something like this.

**Get all attributes in each element**

```
foreach ($b as $b2) {
    if ($b2->hasAttributes()) {
        foreach ($p->attributes as $attr) {
          $name = $attr->nodeName;
          $value = $attr->nodeValue;
          echo 'Attribute ' . $name . ' - ' . $value . '<br />';
        }
    }
}
```

**Get specific attributes from an element**

```
foreach ($b as $b2) {
    if ($b2->hasAttributes()) {
        $titlelink = $b2->attributes->getNamedItem('href')->value;
    }
}
```

You'll need to add in some checks to make sure that the attribute you're trying to select actually exists. That way you're not trying to grab the `href` attribute on a `span` tag.